# How do I map through an unnamed array in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, api

I have an array that looks like this.

[{"id":19,"name":"asd","salary":123},{"id":20,"name":"wer","salary":1}]

But when I try to map through it in React I get an Error

Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function EmployeeList() {
const [data, setData] = useState({ items : [] });

const getEmployees = () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee-list")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
    })
};

useEffect(() => {
    getEmployees();
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {data.map((employee) =>
                <li>{employee.name}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
export default EmployeeList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not setting `data` to an array, but an object at first. Use this instead:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

This assumes that your data comes back from the API as you specified, i.e., as an array. If instead it comes back in the format suggested by your original initial value then you'd need to use:

```js
   {data && data.items && data.items.map((employee) =>
```